# nav-pills и прокрутка

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как сделать, что бы `nav-pills` при прокрутке в низ, цеплялся за вечернюю границу экрана?
Взял из одного примера

ul.nav-pills {
    position: fixed;
}

Но это мне не походит, т.к. оно вообще фиксируется
Что бы было более понятно, по такому же принципу работает столбик "ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ РУКОВОДСТВА" http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=476286585
Не знаю, как сделать так же как там?

Comment: Не могу пройти по ссылке, но вы имеет в виду что-то вроде `position: sticky`? http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html

Comment: да, но я уже нашел, то что искал. Мне помогло [Bootstrap Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix), забыл написать, что этот элемент от бутстрапа. Вот помог [этот пример](https://codepen.io/Craig-Watson/pen/XbjGex) что бы разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Нашел то, что искал [Bootstrap Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)